# Is it possible to show a new taskbar in windows 11? (like showing more of my taskbar icons by pressing an arrow down)

Tags: windows-11

In windows 10, there is a feature where if there are too many taskbar icons, then it will show two arrows where if you press the down one, it shows a new taskbar with more icons. Is there any way (including registry hacks) to implement this into windows 11?

Comment: Windows 11 is quite different than Windows 10 and the Taskbar is very different.  Open Taskbar settings and try Taskbar Corner Overflow. That is how it happens in Windows 11 Preview and Production. I have both now. Let me know, please, if this works for you and I will make it an answer.

Comment: Thank you, this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In windows 10, there is a feature where if there are too many taskbar
> icons, then it will show two arrows where if you press the down one,
> it shows a new taskbar with more icons. Is there any way ..... to
> implement this into windows 11?

Windows 11 is quite different than Windows 10 and the Taskbar is very different. Open Taskbar settings and try Taskbar Corner Overflow.

That is how it happens in Windows 11 Preview and Production. I have both now.

This is new but it should help you and most likely work for you.

Comment: Its the sys tray not the taskbar, quite confusing Microsoft renamed it corner overflow.

Comment: Windows 11 tends to be confusing in a number of areas including this one calling it "ease of use!"