# Win11 Create custom toolbar

Tags: desktop-toolbar

In windows 10, on the taskbar, I could right click an open area and select **Toolbars | New Toolbar...** and create a custom toolbar onto which I could add some frequently used applications.

For example, the following shows two custom toolbars named **Local** and **QuickRef**

[image]

On the windows taskbar these would appear as follows:

[image]

**How can I do this in Windows 11, everything I've searched for doesn't work.**

Searches include:

- https://superuser.com/a/1684849/331605 - This seems like it might work but I don't understand how to do this.

I tried selecting the option

[image]

as I think the superuser question/answer suggested, but I didn't know how to create it from there.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x63ahnPF5rg&t=3s - Windows 11 Taskbar Customization Tutorial

Update: Someone commented that this is no longer supported in Windows 11.  Is there a work around to have a list of items appear easily like a popup menu?

Comment: That feature (available in Windows 10 and Prior) was removed in Windows 11 and has shown no sign of coming back.

Comment: “Is there a work around to have a list of items appear easily like a popup menu?” - No, the feature was removed from Windows 11

Comment: FYI: “Select the far corner of the taskbar to show the desktop” is a option that only exists on specific Windows Insider builds of Windows 11 and has nothing to do with the feature your looking for

Comment: @John, if you want to answer this question with what you put in your comment and provide a link to any supporting documentation (if any exists), I'll accept your response as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see  [Windows 11 custom toolbar](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-did-my-custom-toolbar-shortcuts-go-in/edbe0497-18f1-4043-8e8e-b8ae9b52c74a)

Natively, the toolbar has been removed (Production and Insider Windows 11).

Some third party tools (Winaero for instance) have tried to put it back with limited success.

I have just adapted to Windows 11 as it is and that is working well for me.